# When fitting a model in Amos with ordinal data do I use Bollen stine adjustment or Baysian techniques?

Tags: bayesian, bootstrap, ordinal-data, goodness-of-fit, amos

I am trying to run a model validation/fit in AMOS using 18 items and three factors. The data is ordinal (1-4 scale) for each item. My data is non-normal both on a univariate and multivariate level. I am unsure whether I should estimate using Bayesian techniques or whether I should use a ML method and adjust using the Bollen Stine bootstrap method. When I try and do the Bayesian approach it doesn't run well (I have to make the tuning paramater so small) and I also get some negative values (which when I try and specify '0' as the least value it won't run at all). When I do a ML method and the bootstrapping the model it works better. In this case I have a ns chi square (using the adjusted measure)and mostly good measures of fit. I guess I would prefer it if I could use the ML method with the Bollen Stine, but want to make sure I am doing what is considered appropriate in the literature for ordinal data .